# PHP Guzzle 5 - Post Request Not Asynchronous?

Tags: guzzle

I have the following Guzzle 5 request:

```
$this->guzzle->post("http://endpoint/i/control", array(
    'body' => array(
        'keyone' => 'valueone',
        'keytwo' => 'valuetwo' 
    ),
    'future' => true
));
```

I am under the impression that the above is an async operation because the `future` key is set to `true`.  I control the endpoint the above request hits, and when I put a 5 second sleep function in the script that serves the endpoint, my request takes 5 seconds longer.

How do I serve a true non-blocking asynchronous request using Guzzle 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, to do true async operations using Guzzle 5, you have to bolt it onto something like [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/) - which gives PHP the kind of event loop behavior you see in JavaScript.